# MySQL select non null columns on pivoted table

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I'm still having some troubles to understand pivoted tables, but I managed to do this working query:

```
select region,
sum(case when rescheduleCause = 'CLOSED' then round(reschedulePercentage,2) end) as 'CLOSED',
sum(case when rescheduleCause = 'RESHUFFLE' then round(reschedulePercentage,2) end) as 'RESHUFFLE',
sum(case when rescheduleCause = 'NEW PRIORITY' then round(reschedulePercentage,2) end) as 'NEW PRIORITY'

from fancy_table
group by region
```

I'm getting the following result which calculations are correct:

```
region  | CLOSED | RESHUFFLE | NEW PRIORITY
___________________________________________
RegionA | 23.08  | NULL      | 38.46
RegiobB | 23.08  | NULL      | 7.69
```

My problem in that `RESHUFFLE` column full of `NULL` values. My desired result set would look like this:

```
region  | CLOSED | NEW PRIORITY
___________________________________________
RegionA | 23.08  | 38.46
RegiobB | 23.08  | 7.69
```

I know this can be achieved if I modify this query into a stored procedure using a dynamic sql, but the columns I need are as limitated as these ones, so I think it's not really that necessary. I've tried:

```
    ifnull(sum(case when rescheduleCause = 'RESHUFFLE' then round(reschedulePercentage,2) end),0) as 'RESHUFFLE',
where `RESHUFFLE` is not null
where 'RESHUFFLE' is not null
having `RESHUFFLE` is not null
```

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: A SQL query has a pre-defined set of columns.  You can only vary the number of columns using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are right of course, I just thought there was a way without using dynamic SQL. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are querying in SQL you need to know the number of columns ahead of time, you can't just exclude columns on the fly. If you are going to have an unknown number of columns, then you'll need to use dynamic SQL to first create a sql string that will be executed.

In MySQL this can be done using prepared statements.  This will first query your table to only return the `rescheduleCause` values that you actually have. These values are concatenated together into a sql string, then you'll use this string to create your final query to be executed:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(case when rescheduleCause = ''',
      rescheduleCause,
      ''' then round(reschedulePercentage,2) end) AS ',
      replace(rescheduleCause, ' ', '')
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from fancy_table;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT region, ', @sql, ' 
                    from fancy_table
                    group by region');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15edc/2)

Comment: I thought there was a way, but I knew using dynamic SQL was the real deal. I still need more practice with these kind of statements. You've been helpful in this and other MySQL questions I've posted, I'm learning a lot. Thanks for your help!